# Add to cart not working after login in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento add to cart not working after login but without login its works fine. Here is my website [url](http://www.1able.com.au/abletest/index.php)

Please look into this

Comment: Please put the URL in your question.

Comment: Mohit, Please look into this

Comment: Please check /var/report folder of your installation. There are some errors.
Please check and let me know.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Strange, i am not getting this issue . Please check my live site http://www.1able.com.au                                                                                                            I am searching into it from 2 days.                                                                                            please check my live site

Comment: Please go to **errors** folder of your magento installation and rename local.xml.sample to local.xml.

Comment: Yes i did Mohit

Comment: Mohit, please look into this, i am trying to fix issue from 2 days, but not getting that, how is it possible that "Add to Cart" button working without login and after login its not working...  Please help

Comment: Have you tried solution of @MagikVishal?

Comment: Yes, i tried but its not working...

Comment: Can you update your question and add what is in the log files?

Comment: Here is system.log file data->                                            2016-07-19T13:14:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : Comment not terminated 
&lt;!-- &lt;block before=&quot;-&quot; type=&quot;vcatalog/vcatalog&quot; name=&quot;  in /home/c1able23/public_html/abletest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

Comment: It means that there is a module vcatalog, whose xml has problems. Some comment has not been terminated properly.

Comment: Now it is not showing any error but "Add to Cart" button still not working.  I checked it on both localhost and server.. What should i do guys please help

Comment: Hello Mohit, My issue is solved. I comment validator condition in "productAddToCartForm.submit" function like this-         productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {          
        //if (this.validator.validate()) {                                    Now its working, Thanks you for your efforts.

Comment: Great to know. and sorry that I could not help..

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in /var/log within your root Magento installation

There will usually be two files by default, exception.log and system.log.

If the directories or files don't exist, create them and give them the correct permissions, then enable logging within Magento by going to System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes

Also we can remove # from below code in index.php with magento root directory

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Hii Vishal, I tried but its still not working.  Please help